# Type mismatch error in Oracle SQL correlated subquery when comparing dates

Tags: sql, oracle, type-mismatch

I'm executing a big Oracle SQL select statement, with multiple (about 25) correlated subqueries in the select part of the outer query. The basic idea is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ..., (select from ... where ...), ...
FROM table1, table2, table3 ...
WHERE ...
AND ...
ORDER BY column1
```

I'm getting stuck on the following piece of code which is present in every correlated subquery:

```
AND to_date(foin.BEGINDATUM, 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
BETWEEN to_date(beha.STARTDATUM, 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
AND to_date(beha.EINDDATUM, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

I am getting the error 'type mismatch', in some cases.
This piece of code makes sure some data from one table with the alias 'foin' has a starting date between two dates from another table aliased as 'beha'. All columns have the DATE data type, it might be possible they have NULL values, but even when adding the NVL function in my piece of code it still gives me the type mismatch error.

The following solution was a good idea but didn't solve the error message:

```
AND trunc(foin.BEGINDATUM) BETWEEN trunc(beha.STARTDATUM) 
AND trunc(NVL(beha.EINDDATUM, '01/01/2100'))
```

Anyone has an idea?

Edit: related question: is this error only caused by comparing two fields with different datatypes or comparing a date to a NULL value or could there be another explanation?

Edit2: the result of this oracle sql query is put into MS Excel, the connection is made with an ODBC which I don't really know anything about. Could this error be related to MS Excel?

Comment: It's totally useless to convert a `DATE` column to a date using the `to_date()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all three columns are already of data type `date`, there is no need to call `to_date`.  That would force the dates to be implicitly cast to a `varchar2`, using the session's current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` before being explicitly converted back to a `date` using the specified format mask.  If the two masks are different, you'll get an error.

Assuming that you want to ignore the time component of all three columns

```
AND trunc( foin.begindatum ) BETWEEN trunc( beha.startdatum ) 
                                 AND trunc( beha.einddatum )
```

Comment: Justin, thanks for your answer, it makes sense. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem, I still get the error, even when adding the NVL function in case there is no end date:    AND trunc(foin.BEGINDATUM) BETWEEN trunc(beha.STARTDATUM) AND trunc(NVL(beha.EINDDATUM, '01/01/2100'))

Comment: @Benjamin - Don't use a string as the second argument of the `NVL` function.  Since the first parameter is a `date`, the second parameter should be a `date` as well.  Either call `to_date` on the string or use a date literal `date '2100-01-01'`.  If that doesn't solve the problem, I would wager that the error is not coming from the snippet of SQL you posted but from somewhere else in your query where you are confusing strings and dates.

Comment: thanks for your help, it gave me some insight in data types. In the end the "type mismatch" was just a general error message which would show up with any SQL error (not syntax errors but errors when executing the query).